# Video file location of dynamic wallpaper preview in system preferences

Tags: macos, catalina, preferences, wallpaper

i want to know the location of the little video that keeps on playing in a loop when we select a dynamic wallpaper ( Catalina for eg) and turn it to dynamic mode in system preferences.
Anyone knows where it is stored?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a separate video.

The preference pane loads the different components of the HEIC and fades between them.

Evidence:

- Creating your own dynamic wallpaper only requires the HEIC and the animation plays in the preference pane fine without needing to also create a video.
- Watching file events shows the following file loads when changing desktop background selection from The Beach to The Lake; no video file is loaded.

  ```
    501   1528 com.apple.preference.desktopscre  15 /System/Library/Desktop Pictures/The Beach.heic 
    501   1528 com.apple.preference.desktopscre  15 /System/Library/Desktop Pictures/.thumbnails/The Beach.heic 
    501   1528 com.apple.preference.desktopscre  15 /System/Library/Desktop Pictures/The Lake.heic 
    501   1530 VTDecoderXPCService   4 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleGVA.framework/Resources/Info.plist 
    501    398 Dock          34 /System/Library/Desktop Pictures/The Lake.heic 
    501   1528 com.apple.preference.desktopscre  16 /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/Resources/default.metallib 
    501   1528 com.apple.preference.desktopscre  16 /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/Resources/default.metallib 
    501    398 Dock          34 /System/Library/Desktop Pictures/The Lake.heic
  ```